# Supabase types errors

Tags: typescript, supabase

Im using supabase with typescript and get some errors. I see them in webstorm, but not in vscode. Could u help me?

```
supabase
      .channel('custom-all-channel')
      .on(
        'postgres_changes',
        { event: '*', schema: 'public', table: 'players_online' },
        (payload) => {
          if (payload.eventType === 'INSERT') {
            players = [...players, { name: payload.new.name, id: payload.new.id }]
          }
          if (payload.eventType === 'DELETE') {
            players = players.filter((pl) => pl.id !== payload.old.id)
          }
        }
      )
      .subscribe()
```

I get 2 errors:

1. Argument type "postgres_changes" is not assignable to parameter type `${REALTIME_LISTEN_TYPES.BROADCAST}`
2. Argument type {schema: string, event: string, table: string} is not assignable to parameter type {event: string}

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code seems fine, and it is working just fine in VS Code, right? There might be something wrong with Webstorm's Typescript parser.

Comment: I have the same issue with vsCode and my code doesn't work.